# C++ error: no matching function for call to

Tags: c++, class, parameters, constructor, abstract

Here's the error I got : 
"no matching function for call to 'MemberForTest::MemberForTest'..."

Here is the code:

```
#include "Base.h"
#include "Date.h"

class MemberForTest: public tp::Base
{
public:
    MemberForTest(std::string& name, std::string& firstname,
            Date& birthday, std::string& telephone);

};




class Member
{
public:
    Member() :
        perso("Hall", "roger", (12,12,1990), "(999) 444-4545")
    {
    };

    MemberForTest perso;
};
```

Base is an abstract class. My teacher used the same approach to get to the base class constructor and he does not need to create a function (MemberForTest::MemberForTest). Even if I create the function, the error is still there. Can you help me?

Also, I probably have to pass an object date (Date date(12,12,1990)) rather than (12,12,1990) as parameters. How can I do that?

Comment: `Date(12, 12, 1990)`, although it's unclear (and highly suspect) why the constructor receives everything by reference.

Comment: No implicit conversion from int 1990 to class Date? Shocking...

Comment: Better makee the constructor receive constant references instead of mutable refereces

Answer (score 1):

The expression that you use to initialize `Date`, namely

```
(12,12,1990)
```

is a comma expression that evaluates to an `int` (specifically, `1990`, the last number in the chain of comma-separated numbers). The error indicates that an `int` is incompatible with a `Date`.

Modify your code to construct a `Date` object instead. Unfortunately, you cannot do it inline, because `MemberForTest` constructor takes the `Date` parameter by non-constant reference. If you change the constructor to take parameters by constant reference, like this

```
MemberForTest(const std::string& name, const std::string& firstname,
        const Date& birthday, const std::string& telephone);
```

you should be able to do this:

```
Member() :
    perso("Hall", "roger", Date(12,12,1990), "(999) 444-4545")
{
};
```

Comment: The string refs, too.

Comment: @jrok Ah, you're right, `string` refs should be `const` too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When a parameter is declared as a reference to non-const, such as `std::string& name`, its argument needs to be an lvalue (a named object). You're passing string literals - these are arrays of characters, not `std::string`, and need to be converted. The result of a conversion is a temporary object, an rvalue. The language rule says that these cannot be passed to a reference to non-const.

You need to either declare the constructor to take `const std::string&` (since you won't be changing the arguments), or create an object of `std::string` type first:

```
void foo(std::string& s);
std::string str;
foo(str);
```

Also, `(12,12,1990)` does not create a temporary `Date` object (for that you'd need to use functional style cast - `Date(12,12,1990)`). It's a parenthesized expression, using the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator), that evaluates the left hand operands, discards them, and return the rightmost operand (integer literal `1990`).

And the same applies as with `string` parameters, you need to take `const Date&`.